# why is this simple assignment statement not working(vba)?

Tags: vba, excel

As I am new to vba scripting I am unable to figure out where am I going wrong in this simple assignment statement.
I have initialized my variables in ThisWorkBook and trying to use those in sheet1.

Code:

```
Public count1 As Integer
Public count2 As Integer
Public count3 As Integer
Public row13 As Integer
Public srow8 As Integer
Public erow8 As Integer
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

count1 = 18
count2 = 26
count3 = 26
Sheet1.setValues
Sheet1.getValues
End Sub

Sub setValues()
row13 = ThisWorkbook.count1
Debug.Print (row13)
srow8 = ThisWorkbook.count2
erow8 = ThisWorkbook.count3
End Sub

Sub getValues()
Debug.Print ("row13")
Debug.Print (row13)
Debug.Print ("srow8")
Debug.Print (srow8)
Debug.Print ("erow8")
Debug.Print (srow8)
End Sub
```

(all variables are global)
When I try to print these values there is no value printed.
I don't understand where did I go wrong?
It would be great help if you can help me with this.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: `row13`, `srow8` and `erow8` are declared as module-level in what I assume is your `ThisWorkbook` code, but then you are trying to use them outside of the module in the `Sheet1` code.

Comment: yes you are right that it is outside Thisworkbook code, but as the variable is public then shouldn't i be able to use this from sheet1 also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Public` variables are accessible from any area of your code, not just the object they are defined in.  That does not mean that you don't have to specify the object they are in when you want to refer to them so, for instance, ones you included in your `ThisWorkbook` object would be referred to as `ThisWorkbook.count1`, etc.  To avoid qualifying the variables with the relevant object, you can make the variables `Public` within a standard code module.

I believe what you are trying to do is as follows:

In your `ThisWorkbook` code module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    count1 = 18
    count2 = 26
    count3 = 26
    Sheet1.setValues
    Sheet1.getValues
End Sub
```

In your `Sheet1` code module:

```
Sub setValues()
    row13 = count1
    Debug.Print row13
    srow8 = count2
    erow8 = count3
End Sub

Sub getValues()
    Debug.Print "row13"
    Debug.Print row13
    Debug.Print "srow8"
    Debug.Print srow8
    Debug.Print "erow8"
    Debug.Print srow8
End Sub
```

In a general code module (perhaps `Module1`):

```
Public count1 As Integer
Public count2 As Integer
Public count3 As Integer
Public row13 As Integer
Public srow8 As Integer
Public erow8 As Integer
```

Comment: I had Public variables under ThisWorkbook general code module
thanks for helping

Comment: Yes, because they were in `ThisWorkbook` they were accessible using `ThisWorkbook.count1`, which is why it worked when setting `count1`  within `Workbook_Open` (implicitly defaulting to `count1` within the current object, i.e. `ThisWorkbook`), and when setting the value of `row13` within `setValues` (where `row13` implicitly referred to a procedure-level scoped variable, because no module level scoped variable existed) to `Thisworkbook.count1` (explicitly referring to the `count1` variable within the `ThisWorkbook` object.